# NoMethodError (undefined method) for embedded object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm trying to save a Mongo::Document which embeds another one. My classes:

```
class Block 
  include Mongoid::Document    
  field :name, type: String
  field :text, type: String
  embeds_many :replies         
end
```

Other class:

```
class Reply
    include Mongoid::Document    
    field :content_type, type: String
    field :title, type: String
    field :payload, type: String
    embedded_in :block
end
```

And create method in controller:

```
def create
        @block = Block.where(:name => block_params[:name])        
        @quick_reply = Reply.new(title: params[:block][:quick_replies][:title], payload: params[:block][:quick_replies][:payload] )
        @block.replies.push(@quick_reply)          
        @block.name = params[:block][:name]
        @block.text = params[:block][:text]      
        if (@block.save)
            respond_to do |format|
                format.html {render :template => "block/text/edit"}
            end            
        end        
    end
```

I'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `replies' for #<Mongoid::Criteria:0x71cf550>
```

I want to learn why and how can I solve the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@block = Block.where(:name => block_params[:name])
```

`.where` does not give you a single record - instead it gives you a criteria (somewhat like an `ActiveRecord::Relation`) which is a lazy loading object that may contain several or even no records at all.

Instead you need to use `.find_by` to select a single record:

```
@block = Block.find_by(name: block_params[:name])
```

This will also raise a `Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound` if the Block cannot be found - which is a good thing. If the block cant be found trying to create a nested record would be pointless.

There is also a much better way to create nested records - by using  [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](https://github.com/rsl/stringex). This is also useful if you want to edit a document and its children in a single action.

But what you are probably looking for in the first place is to make replies a nested resource:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :blocks do
  resources :replies, only: [:new, :create]
end
```

---

```
class RepliesController

  before_action :set_block

  # GET /blocks/:id/replies/new
  def new
    @reply = @block.replies.new
  end

  # POST /blocks/:id/replies
  def create
    @reply = @block.replies.new(reply_params)
    if @reply.save
      redirect_to @block, success: 'Thank you for your reply'
    else
      render :new, error: 'Your reply could not be saved'
    end
  end

  private
  def set_block
    @block = Block.find(params[:id])
  end

  def reply_params
    params.require(:reply).permit(:title, :payload)
  end
end
```

---

```
<%= form_for([@block, @reply || @block.replies.new]) do |f| %>
  <div class="row">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <%= f.label :payload %>
    <%= f.text_field :payload %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```